# JTree in an Eclipse view, dimension issue plugin development Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, plugins, swt

I  have been following this tutorial to embed a JTree component into an Eclipse view.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/EmbededSwingAWTcomponentstoSWT.htm

The issue I have is that it doesn't print the whole tree, and I can't figure out how to resize it using differents layout from SWT or Swing.

By the way I am completely new to Swing components embedded to Swt.

Here's my code, and a screenshoot showing the display problem :

[display problem on the tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBQGf.png)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.awt.SWT_AWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;

import testbutton.handlers.SampleHandler;

public class viewMap4j extends ViewPart {

  public viewMap4j() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  @Override
  public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    parent.setLayout(new RowLayout());
    Button newProject = new Button(parent, SWT.COLOR_DARK_BLUE);
    newProject.setText("New  project");
    newProject.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
      public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        switch (e.type) {
          case SWT.Selection:
            // Some Methods..
            break;
        }
      }
    });

    Button generate = new Button(parent, SWT.COLOR_DARK_BLUE);
    generate.setText("Generate...");
    generate.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
      public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        switch (e.type) {
          case SWT.Selection:
            // Some Methods..
            break;
        }
      }
    });

    Button openProject = new Button(parent, SWT.COLOR_DARK_BLUE);
    openProject.setText("Open project");
    openProject.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
      public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        switch (e.type) {
          case SWT.Selection:
            // Some Methods..
            break;
        }
      }
    });

    Button saveProject = new Button(parent, SWT.COLOR_DARK_BLUE);
    saveProject.setText("Save");
    saveProject.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
      public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        switch (e.type) {
          case SWT.Selection:
            // Some Methods..
            break;
        }
      }

    });

    Composite jtreeComp = new Composite(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED);

    // jtreeComp.setBounds(500,500,800,800);
    jtreeComp.setSize(1000, 1000);
    java.awt.Frame fileTableFrame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(jtreeComp);
    java.awt.Panel panel = new java.awt.Panel(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
    fileTableFrame.add(panel);
    JTree fileTable = new JTree();
    fileTable.setSize(300, 300);
    fileTable.setDoubleBuffered(true);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(fileTable);
    panel.add(scrollPane);

  }

  @Override
  public void setFocus() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is there a reason for using JTree rather than sticking to all SWT components by using the SWT Tree control (or JFace TreeViewer)? Eclipse plugins are normally completely SWT

Comment: Yes,  I have some methods using the JTree component that I want to add later.

Comment: You might be missing setting grid data. Set Grid Data on `jtreeComp`. `jtreeComp.setLayoutData( new GridLayout() ); jtreeComp.setGridData( new GridData( GridData.BOTH ) )`;

Comment: @svasa it doesn't compile when I tried it

Comment: @LoganWlv that code was little off. Use : `jtreeComp.setLayoutData( new GridData( GridData.FILL_BOTH ) );` `jtreeComp.setLayout( new FillLayout() );` Let me know if that works.

Comment: @svasa so it gives me this :

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData cannot be cast to org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowData

I tried to use FillLayout for the cast issue on the parent, it works for the JTree component but the buttons are filling the view and it doesn't look good.

I found a solution using a composite : 
    `Composite buttonPanel = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new RowLayout());`

then I did add every buttons to `buttonPanel` , and somehow it did the trick